# URL rewriting in PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, web

Hello everyone i have made this application in PHP with different pages linked together with each other. The application is working fine,but the URL generated are a lot messy and complicated. I have three pages in my application namely

```
1.index.php (the default file)
2.video.php (the category page)
3.video-detail.php(the page for playing the video)
```

And the name of the root folder is `april`

Now the links which are generated for the application are.

```
http://localhost/april/video?cat_id=2&category=Programming-Language
```

Considering i am in the second page browsing some category after taking some input from the user in the first page. Now i am trying that the URL should be a lot cleaner than this. For eg: the URL should be in this format .

```
http://localhost/april/Programming-Language.
```

I know this task is achieved using .htacess, but i can't really understand it's approach. So any help regarding this topic is highly appreciated.

Comment: which framework you are using?

Comment: Just basic PHP. along with apache server.

Comment: you have to make RewriteEngine on in .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://localhost/april/video?category=Programming-Language&cat_id=2`

This can be transformed into:
`http://localhost/Programming-Language/2`

(notice that I shifted `cat_id` to the end, since I suspected it to be a page number.)

This is accomplished by placing the following in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /april/video?category=$1&cat_id=$2 [L]
```

Obviously you can then pick up the variables via `$_GET` request (`$_GET['category']`)

Comment: tried this approach . did'nt work out .. this is my htaccess file.

Comment: @HarjeevSingh For starters, try it without the rest of the stuff in there, also, make sure you use this properly.

Comment: So i came across this code `RewriteRule    ^products/([0-9]+)/?$    show_a_product.php?product_id=$1  ` , but i can't seem to figure what is converting what . I mean the tutorial said that it would look in the URL for a particular pattern and then convert it into the complete messy link. But shouldn't the process be the other way around.

Comment: With the help of .htaccess file i was able to trim down the URL to

`http://localhost/april/24_april/24_april/video-library/2/Programming-Language`. Now the issue is every time i run the application it firsts loads the messy URL , and when i edit it accordingly then the page also gets loaded. So is there any way that the application could directly load the clean URL, rather than the messy URL.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes in the `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

If you want more information check these links

> 1.http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource
>   2.https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules